# Entity Framework - create instance of subclass when a parent instance is already saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following classes:

```
[Table("Organization", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Organization
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /* Other organization attributes */
}

[Table("Customer", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Customer : Organization
{
    /* Extends organization for customer specific details */
}

Organization o = new Organization { Name = "worlddata.online" };
db.Organization.Add(o);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Organizations can be created at any time as part of a sales cycle. At some point in time an Organization may become a Customer. I therefore need to be able to create an instance of a Customer for an Organization that already exists in the data model.

Is there a correct/easy way to do this?

Attempting to cast an Organization to a Customer is not possible as retrieved entities are proxies which cannot be cast. I can add the key for the customer directly to the database using:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ([OrganizationId]) VALUES('" + o.OrganizationId.ToString() + "')");
```

but if the parent Organization has already been loaded I will get an error when I try to access the customer: e.g. the call

```
Customer cu = (from x in db.Customer where x.Name == "worlddata.online" select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

will generate:

```
'DatabaseContext.Organization' must have unique primary keys. However, an instance of type 'overwatch.data.Customer' and an instance of type 'overwatch.data.Organization' both have the same primary key value
```

I have tried attaching a Customer with the correct OrganizationId to the model and I have even tried using the AddOrUpdate function in System.Data.Entity.Migrations but EF always creates a new Organization instance with a unique Id.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is a customer an organization or does an organization have a customer(s)? An is-a relationship doesn't make sense here, but has-a does.

Comment: A customer will always be an organization. In a purely general solution an organization may also have customers but I am not attempting to model that at present.

Comment: You should be able to delete the organization and add the customer in one transaction. But what about foreign keys to `Organization`? How would you deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an architectural issue to me.  Instead of making `Customer` a subclass of `Organization`, I would make it an "add-on table".  That way everything has an entry in the Organization table, with an optional entry in Customer that has a foreign key pointing back to Organization.

You would be able to see if an org is a customer by checking the org's `.Customer` property, and access data from it like `SomeOrg.Customer.SomeCustomerProperty`, or if using the new C# features, `SomeOrg?.Customer.SomeCustomerProperty`.

When you want to convert an Organization to a customer you just add a Customer row for them.

If you *really* want to, you could add some "wrapper" properties to Customer that are just calls in to the Customer instance, like this.

```
public string SomeCustomerProperty 
{
    get 
    { 
        return this?.Customer.SomeCustomerProperty;
    }
}
```

These should have the [NotMapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped) attribute applied to them so that EF doesn't try to use them to generate columns.

Comment: I don't like the idea of implementing anything to do with a Customer on Organization as this breaks basic object inheritance. I could see the creation of a Customer class that encapsulates an Organization as a possible solution. This however is an architectural compromise. EF maps the tables and data for the inherited solution beautifully. It seems a shame if there would be a need to break inheritance.

Comment: Beautifully, except for where you need to "trick" EF in to thinking that an object is actually of a different type.  I find that usually when I end up fighting the framework like that I'm doing something wrong.